# Конвертация из XML в вид...

Tags: c#, xml

Приветствую! Может быть кто-то догадывается какой тут нужно составить код( метод) на C# , чтобы из вида XML  получить вид как внизу:

```
<interfaces>                            
  <interface>
    <name>ge-0/0/2</name>
    <unit>
      <name>0</name>
      <family>
        <inet>
          <address>
            <name>1.1.1.1/32</name>
          </address>
        </inet>
      </family>
    </unit>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
```

**Нужен такой:**

```
ge-0/0/2 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 1.1.1.2/32;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то не понял, у вас внизу, это что за представление данных такое?

Comment: есть такое. это junos

Comment: Не знаком с таким форматом. На выходе он должен быть представлен в текстовом виде? Если да, то есть смысл посмотреть в сторону XSLT.

Comment: Возможно и подойдет!спасибо!